# How to currentdate.getDate() in JavaScript for Lightning Web Component?

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to write a test class to automate my several tests in register forms, but the JavaScript currentdate.getDate() isn't working for some reason that I don't know.

I'm trying the following:

```
    tester : function (component, event, helper) {
    document.getElementById("inputfield1").value = "Test" + currentdate.getDate();
    }
```

Until the string, the code works fine. The problem is only the currentdate.getDate();

Can someone please help me with this? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just got an answer. Goes like this:

```
  var d = new Date(); //d stands for date
  document.getElementById("inputfield").value = "Test" + d.getHours() + d.getMinutes();
```